# ListView fails to scroll

Tags: react-native

As you can see in the attached GIF, I can't scroll through the `ListView`. The view snaps back to the original position as soon as I release the mouse.

I've read over the documentation and it seems like scrolling should *just work*. Here's the implementation of `render()`:

```
render: function(){
  return (
    <ListView
      automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
      initialListSize={9}
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderTrack}
      renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}/>
  );
```

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your ListView might actually be quite small but not appear that way do to visible overflow. Try setting `flex: 1` or `height: 587` on your ListView's style property.

Comment: Setting the height did the trick! May I ask why you picked 587?

Comment: Your screenshot was 587px tall =). A more general solution is to use flex:1 through your view hierarchy up to the root.

Comment: Using just `flex: 1` didn't fix it. I don't think I can just set a static height, however, as it needs to be compatible with different iPhone sizes. EDIT: turns out this ListView's parent container didn't have `flex: 1`, that did the trick.

Comment: Thanks @ide for the comment. But why does one have to set flex: 1 through the entire view hierarchy??

Comment: @Andru The goal is to have ListView's height expand to fill the screen. If you put `flex: 1` on only the ListView, it will expand to fill its parent but the parent will not expand to fill the grandparent, hence the chain of `flex: 1`. You can also put `flex-direction: row` or fixed heights on the ancestors -- the point is that you need the ListView to fill the screen.

Answer (score 22):

The only time I've seen this is when contentContainerStyle is set to flex:1. Remove the flex if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks! been looking around for 30 mins haha!

Answer (score 9):

setting `flex:1` to list's parent did the trick for me.

Comment: Worked like a charm. This answer should get more upvotes!

Comment: it would be great if someone could explain it :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I had a `View` wrapping the `ListView`, I removed the outer `View` and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to this property, I assume you only have one, maybe add a sticky header per row?:

> renderSectionHeader function
>
> (sectionData, sectionID) => renderable
>
> If provided, a sticky header is rendered for this section. The sticky
>   behavior means that it will scroll with the content at the top of the
>   section until it reaches the top of the screen, at which point it will
>   stick to the top until it is pushed off the screen by the next section
>   header.