# ListView not scrolling on Chromebook

Tags: listview, react-native, chromebook

Currently working on a react-native project on Chromebook and some of my ListViews refuse to scroll. This problem is strange because they work fine on regular android devices, iOS devices and even in other parts of my application, however in 2 specific cases they just won't scroll.

I have tried everything all the suggestions on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874559/listview-fails-to-scroll) but none seem to work. I am wondering if there is something different about the Chromebook that is causing this?

Here is a snippet of the ListView code:

```
render() {
    const margin    = PadletCell.sectMargin();
    const cellStyle = Settings.isTablet() ? styles.tabletContainer : {};
    const listStyle = Settings.isTablet() ? styles.listStyleTablet : styles.listStyleMobile;
    const margins   = Settings.isTablet() ? {marginLeft:margin, marginRight:margin} : {};
    return (
      <View style={[styles.flex, listStyle, margins]} onLayout={this.onLayout.bind(this)}>
        <ListView
          renderFooter={()=><View style={{height:96}}/>}
          style={[styles.listView]}
          enableEmptySections={true}
          removeClippedSubviews={false}
          contentContainerStyle={[cellStyle]}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          ref={listView => this.listView = listView}
          renderRow={(data,section,row) => <PadletCell navigator={this.props.navigator}
                                             id={{section:section,row:row}}
                                             width={this.state.cellWidth}
                                             user={this.state.user}
                                             backOne={true}
                                             data={data}
                                             />}
         refreshControl={
           <RefreshControl
             refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
              onRefresh={this.onRefresh.bind(this)}
           />}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

and here is a snippet of the corresponding styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  listView:{
    paddingTop:Settings.isTablet() ? 16 : 6,
    flex:1,
  },
  listStyleMobile:{
    flex:1,
  },
  listStyleTablet:{
    marginRight:TAB_SECT_MARGIN,
    marginLeft: TAB_SECT_MARGIN,
    flex:1,
  },
  tabletContainer:{
    flexDirection:'row',
    flexWrap:'wrap',
    flex:1,
  },
  flex:{
    flex:1,
  }
});
```

I have tried removing the flex, and hardcoding a height to no avail. The weird thing is, the code is exactly the same in other parts of my app where it does work. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a temporary solution which is a slight hack but works nonetheless, it appears the ScrollView won't scroll unless it has content that is larger than the visible region. For whatever reason not all of the content was loading originally, so I created a async reload method and fired it off about 10 times to fill the screen, because each consecutive reload only loaded 1 additional cell.

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(this.forceReload.bind(this), 500);
}

async forceReload() {
  for (let i=0; i<10; i++) await this.asyncReload();
}

asyncReload() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.onRefresh(resolve);
  });
}

onRefresh(callback=()=>{}) {
  const { data } = this.props;
  let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
  this.setState({ dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data) }, callback);
}
```